# How and can I disable touch events in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, touch

I would like **to force to disable touch events** with **Chrome** and by pass the option set up to automatic by default in the chrome preferences. I know users can disable it in `chrome://flags` but I would like to drive it programmatically.

I have noticed that `'ontouchstart' in window` is not interpreted the same way on each browser.

Is it possible in javascript to reset this value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to bind to the touchmove event:

```
$('*').bind('touchmove', false);
```

Comment: could you explain please ?

Comment: With jQuery, you bind touchmove to false, so when a user starts to move an element via touch, it will disable the behavior.

Comment: This works perfectly.  Used to disable touch swipe on a bootstrap carousel by using it in this format : `$('#carouselId *').bind('touchmove', false);` after the carousel was initialized.